# Random Sampling Based on Date

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to random sample based on dates, I asked a similar question on here a few weeks, but am having trouble trying to convert that to a code to do this more easily based on the same n each day, as opposed to having to write out the below function for each day

```
df[(df.date <= '2019-01-02') & (df.date >= '2019-01-01')].sample(n=3)
df[(df.date <= '2019-01-03') & (df.date >= '2019-01-02')].sample(n=3)
```

but is there a way to do so I don't have to keep writing out the dates, like because I have n=3 every day, I think there must be an easier way to do this, but have looked everywhere and haven't been able to figure it out. I am pretty sure I need to use lambda to do this, but haven't been able to completely figure it out for a one day step, with the exception of:

```
step=datetime.timedelta(1)
```

thank you in advance!

```
date                    random_sample
2019-01-01 00:03:15       No
2019-01-01 00:06:21       No
2019-01-01 02:00:21       No
2019-01-01 08:06:48       No
2019-01-01 10:25:37       No
2019-01-02 00:03:15       No
2019-01-02 00:06:21       No
2019-01-02 02:00:21       No
2019-01-02 08:06:48       No
2019-01-02 10:25:37       No
```

```
date                      random_sample
2019-01-01 00:03:15       Yes
2019-01-01 00:06:21       No
2019-01-01 02:00:21       Yes
2019-01-01 08:06:48       Yes
2019-01-01 10:25:37       No
2019-01-02 00:03:15       No
2019-01-02 00:06:21       Yes
2019-01-02 02:00:21       Yes
2019-01-02 08:06:48       Yes
2019-01-02 10:25:37       No
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and take 3 samples in each group of the same date.

Then you use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to conditionally assign `Yes` to the dates which are in your sample:

```
g = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date).apply(lambda x: x['date'].sample(n=3)).to_numpy()

df['random_sample'] = np.where(df.date.isin(g), 'Yes', df['random_sample'])

print(df)
                 date random_sample
0 2019-01-01 00:03:15           Yes
1 2019-01-01 00:06:21            No
2 2019-01-01 02:00:21            No
3 2019-01-01 08:06:48           Yes
4 2019-01-01 10:25:37           Yes
5 2019-01-02 00:03:15            No
6 2019-01-02 00:06:21           Yes
7 2019-01-02 02:00:21           Yes
8 2019-01-02 08:06:48           Yes
9 2019-01-02 10:25:37            No
```

**Edit**
Filter data on two weeks before now

```
df = df[df.date >= (pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.Timedelta(days=14))]
```

Comment: hey! thank you so much this works really well, the only thing is there anyway to do it with a scheduled like start and end date, on SQL there is like the curdate() function, but is there a similar function or something on python, so that it would start and stop at a certain point?

Comment: You want to filter your dataset on certain dates before apply the sampling? `Curdate` in SQL simply returns the current date. We can do that in python as well. Depends on what you exactly want to do.

Comment: hey, yeah I am trying to do something where it will do like the previous 2 weeks before the most recent week, yeah I can just filter beforehand, but I wasn't sure if that was feasible or not?

Comment: Edited question which includes filtering data on two weeks @JoeMeyer